# How come I can not activate my Virtual Python Environment with 'source env/bin/activate' command?

Tags: python, pylons

I am trying to activate my Virtual Python Environment to use with Pylons but I think I am executing the commands wrong.

```
jem@jem-laptop:~$ source env/bin/activate
bash: env/bin/activate: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?
How should I do it right?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I realize I had to do

```
jem@jem-laptop:~$ ls
Desktop    examples.desktop  Public           shortener.rb
Documents  Mac4Lin_v1.0      ruby-1.9.1-p378  Templates
Downloads  Music             rubygems-1.3.7   Videos
Dropbox    Pictures          setcolors.vim    virtualenv.py
```

And here we see virtualenv.py. From here I just had to

```
jem@jem-laptop:~$ virtualenv ENV
New python executable in ENV/bin/python
Installing setuptools............done.
```

And then

```
jem@jem-laptop:~$ source ENV/bin/activate
(ENV)jem@jem-laptop:~$ deactivate
jem@jem-laptop:~$
```

Solved :)

Comment: On Unix-like systems the command `virtualenv` will not execute the file `virtualenv.py` - at least not directly. --- Anyway I would be interested where did the file `~/virtualenv.py` come from.

Answer (score 7):

I usually do it this way:

```
$ cd the_project_dir
$ . bin/activate
(the_project)$ _
```

I need to be in the project directory anyway to go on with the work.
Obviously `the_project_dir` is the name of a directory where you have created a virtualenv.

Answer (score 6):

In 2.7 version I used this command:

```
$ cd project_name
$ virtualenv venv --distribute
$ source venv/Scripts/activate
(venv)
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple fix:

```
$ virtualenv env
$ cd env/Scripts/
$ . activate
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [virtualenvwrapper](http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/). It makes working with virtualenv a lot simpler, especially if you have more than one virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

On FreeBSD I solved this doing following:

```
# ls mypienv
# mypienv/bin/activate
mypienv/bin/activate: Permission denied.
# chmod +x mypienv/bin/activate
# mypienv/bin/activate
Missing '}'.
```

And you see that script not working but:

```
# ls mypienv/bin/
activate        activate.fish       easy_install-2.7    pip2.7          python2
activate_this.py    activate.ps1        pip         python          python2.7
activate.csh        easy_install        pip2            python-config       wheel
```

Finaly:

```
# python mypienv/bin/activate_this.py
```

And it worked!
P.S. I am new with python python verions 2.7

Answer (score 0):

`env/Scripts/activate` worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Very short answers are usually discouraged. Please consider adding more information. E.g., what exactly did you do with this file? `source env/Scripts/activate`? Something else? What system are you on? Any additional information that could help others?

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, the following worked for me:

`C:\.virtualenvs\env\Scripts>activate.bat`