# volttron installation certificate error

Tags: installation, volttron

I just downloaded the volltron files today from github. When I got to the step to execute:

python bootstrap.py

I got certificate verification errors. Below is the terminal snippet. Has anyone else encountered this?

```
aps@ubuntu:~/volttron/volttron$ python bootstrap.py 
Creating virtual Python environment
Downloading virtualenv DOAP record
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bootstrap.py", line 402, in <module>
    main()
  File "bootstrap.py", line 385, in main
    options.force_version, options.verbose)
  File "bootstrap.py", line 206, in bootstrap
    builder.create(dest, verbose)
  File "bootstrap.py", line 184, in create
    self.download(tmpdir)
  File "bootstrap.py", line 169, in download
    self.get_version()
  File "bootstrap.py", line 160, in get_version
    with contextlib.closing(self._fetch(doap_url)) as response:
  File "bootstrap.py", line 147, in _fetch
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 429, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 447, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1241, in https_open
    context=self._context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1198, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)>
```

Comment: Are you connected to the internet when you run bootstrap.py?

Comment: Yes. I am posting to this website from the same computer. From a firewall perspective, SSL is allowed outbound on my computer and the network.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu and Python are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the error in the development of Virtual Environment for Volttron. I got the same issue. I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

To solve the problem, I followed the steps below to create  Virtual Environment  http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/how-to-use-python-virtualenv

These are the steps followed using the above link:

- Install Virtualenv

`$ sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv`

after that:

```
mkdir ~/virtualenvironment
```

and

```
virtualenv ~/virtualenvironment/my_new_app
```

Lastly, activate your environment:

```
source activate
```

and to exit the virtualenv just type “`deactivate`”.

another easer way at: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3844055

in the first step I named the "virtualenv" `volttron`,

so it will be written as

```
$ virtualenv volttron
```

once I typed the above script in Volttron root, the python virtualenv created under, volttron/bin/python

> New python executable in volttron/bin/python
>
> Installing setuptools............done.

So, to activate in this case: we need to type: `source volttron/bin/activate`

I was able to create agents after doing these steps.

Please let me know if there is any easier way than this.

Thanks,

NOTE: if you do not have the "virtualenv" package, you can install it using : `sudo apt install virtualenv`